# Cannot reload page with document.location.reload(true) in Firefox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox, button

Hi I have a button to reload a page in asp.net mvc4. Here is the code:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="document.location.reload(true);"/>
```

It works fine for Google Chrome. However, when I use IE and Firefox, it gives me this warning:

**To display the webpage again, the browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted. If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click Retry to display the webpage again.**

How do I fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

or

```
window.location.reload()
```

Comment: Anyone know why the MDN example uses document rather than location? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload